How to suppress warning about constant primary key? Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[20600]
I have a table defined to have exactly one row, by using a boolean primary key and a unique constraint. The idea behind this was based on this post from ten years ago: One-Row by Brandstetter. This is intentional and works fine.
But EF Core Validation generates the following warning, which I would like to suppress.

warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[20600]
Property 'Id' on entity type 'Config' is part of a primary or alternate key, but has a constant default value set. Constant default values are not useful for primary or alternate keys since these properties must always have non-null unique values.

How can I suppress this warning?
My table def in Postgres:
CREATE TABLE config (
    id boolean PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT TRUE,
    demo boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    version text NOT NULL,
    venue text,
    CONSTRAINT config_unique CHECK (id)
);

Relevant section of my DbContext.cs:
modelBuilder.Entity<Config>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("config_pkey");

    entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValue(true);
    entity.Property(e => e.Demo).HasDefaultValue(false);
});


Removing the default from the boolean primary key fixed the warning.

id boolean PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT TRUE,

And apparently the missing default does not change the one-row nature of the table, since the constraint is still enforced.

Technically though, can it not have two rows? True and False.

That's what I would have expected, so I tried it, and apparently the constraint prevents a row with Id of False from being created.
